# Symfony2, get locale in repository class

Tags: php, symfony, repository, locale

In my project with symfony2 (2.0) I have a repository class with all querys inside.
But in this querys I need the locale (from session?) but inside the repository I can't get this variable (in the controller I havn't any problem)

In the repository class I tried this:

```
$request = $this->get('request');
$this->get('translator')->getLocale();
```

but doesn't work for me...any idea?

problem.....symfony 2.0...

**EDIT 2**

my techn_note declaration:

```
<?php

namespace EVTS\FrontendBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * EVTS\FrontendBundle\Entity\Tech_note
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="tech_note")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="EVTS\FrontendBundle\Entity\TechNoteRepository")
 */
class Tech_note {
// fields here
}
```

**EDIT**

My repository class:

```
<?php

namespace EVTS\FrontendBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class TechNoteRepository extends EntityRepository {

    public function findNtecById($ntec_id) {
//        var_dump($request = $this->get('request'));
//        var_dump($this->get('translator')->getLocale());
//        var_dump($request->getLocale());

        echo "test";
        die;

    }
}
```

Thanks to all

Comment: Can you put the class where you want to have access to the locale? By the way, you should consider to get at least Symfony 2.3

Comment: at this moment, my repository class is empty, but I edit my post

Comment: So did my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use the locale in a query, you can try to get the locale in the controller and then use it as parameter in the repository function:

```
$locale = $this->get('request')->getLocale();
$result = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeMyBundle:MyEntity')->findNtecByIdAndLocaleOrSomething($id, $locale);
```

The problem with this approach is, you will have to pass the locale as parameter in all functions where you will need it.

Comment: Hi @Gonçalo Cunha, this is not my ideal approach, but works perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is not good approach to try to inject dependency of request/session to your repository. It will make additional troubles for you like if you will need to use the repository at a console command.

You can take a look to Translatable extension https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md

Also possible way is create own listener http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html and listener will pick up the correct locale from session and inject it to the repository, but as I already told Doctrine Translatable extension can do all for you already

Answer (score -1):

You have to create an Event listener:

```
namespace EVTS\FrontendBundle\EventListener;


use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;


class LocaleListener
{
    protected $locale;

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $this->locale = $event->getRequest()->getLocale();
    }

    public function getLocale()
    {
        return $this->locale;
    }
}
```

Then  declare it:

```
#config.yml
services:
    my_listener.locale:
        class:   EVTS\FrontendBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener
        tags:
            - {name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request,  method: onKernelRequest }
```

Now add it in your repository class constructor:

```
namespace EVTS\FrontendBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;

class TechNoteRepository extends EntityRepository {

    protected $locale;


    public function __construct($em, ClassMetadata $class, $localeListener)
    {
        parent::__construct($em, $class);

        $this->locale = $localeListener->getLocale();
    }

    public function findNtecById($ntec_id) {
//        var_dump($request = $this->get('request'));
//        var_dump($this->get('translator')->getLocale());
//        var_dump($request->getLocale());

        echo "test";
        die;

    }
}
```

And last, add it to your EntityRepository declaration

Comment: Hi Med, I like this aproach, but in the "parent::__construct($em, $class);" I have this error all time: Missing argument 3. Any idea? thxs!

Comment: Yes, that's the last phrase of my answer. You just have to add `'@LocaleListener'` as 3rd argument in the declaration of the TechnoteRepository. If you d'ont manage to do it by yourself, please edit your question with the declaration of your `technoteRepository` and I will edit mine.

Comment: Hello and tks again! (I edited my question) you are saying about the  "@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="EVTS\FrontendBundle\Entity\TechNoteRepository")" ?????